# Not able to update ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation (.Net)

Tags: .net, parse-platform, push-notification

I am getting problem with Parse Installation object. Not able to update values after restarting app.

1.If I launch the app for the first time and install device on parse by ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("") it works fine.
Here I am able to add fields in Installation object and also able to update values.
2.But when i restart the app I am not able to update Installation object.
3.Following is the code snippet i have used,

```
var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
installation["myid"] = 123456;
await installation.SaveAsync();
```

4.I debugged code to check what is the issue and observed that "await installation.SaveAsync();" here "SaveAsync"
is returning nothing. Debug pointer gets lost and if i change myid to something else
Example:

```
var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
installation["myid"] = 897562;
await installation.SaveAsync();
```

This change doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug to Parse and it was confirmed a few days ago! Hopefully they're gonna fix this issue in the next update! Here you can check my post on facebook developer: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/844621472295526/?search_id